# Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Ticket\resources\views\user\user_view_table.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

why i'm getting this error every time i click the view button without a value in database??

[the black circle has a complete value. the red circle is not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeZtj.png)

Here is the Sample interface of my testing system:

[This is the interface sample i've working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1hXJ.png)

on model:
public $table = "enduserticket";

```
public function action()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\action');
}

public function enduser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\enduser');
}

public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\status');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\users');
}
```

on Controller (resource show):

```
{
    $info = enduserticket::findorfail($id);
    return view('user.user_view_table',['info' => $info]);
}
```

on view page:

        
           Back
        
        
          
            Reference No.: 
            
              
            
          
          
            Date: 
            
              created_at)); ?>" readonly="true">
            
          
          
            Requestor Name: 
            
              enduser->eufn. ' ' . $info ->enduser->eumn. ' ' .$info->enduser->euln; ?>" readonly="true">
            
          
          
            Position: 
            
              enduser->eupos; ?>" readonly="true">
            
          
          
            Office/Staff: 
            
              enduser->euoffsta; ?>" readonly="true">
            
          
          
            Priority Level:  
            
              prioritylevel; ?>" readonly="true">
            
          
          
            Brief Description of Request: 
            
              {{ $info->description }}
            
          
          
            Type of Request: 
            
              typeofrequest; ?>" readonly="true">
            
          
          
            Date Submitted: 
            
              datesubmitted)); ?>" readonly="true">
            
          
          
            Date Required: 
            
              daterequired)); ?>" readonly="true">
            
          
          
            Handled By: 
            
              users->name; ?>" placeholder="N/A" readonly="true">
            
          
          
            Start Action: 
            
              action->date_start)); ?>" placeholder="N/A" readonly="true">
            
          
          
            End of Action: 
            
              
            
          
          
            Description of Specific Work: 
            
              
            
          
          
            Acceptance Rating: 
            
              
            
          
          
            Remarks:

Comment: Please display code of user_view_table.blade.php

Comment: Sorry m first time in stackoverflow. already edited @SaurabhDhariwal

Comment: actually in the enduser model you have used a method name `User` which should be `user`

Comment: check `$enduser = enduser::findorfail($id); dd($enduser)` then try `dd($enduser->enduserticket)` then try `dd($enduser->users)` in your controller then do

Answer (score 0):

first off all read how blade template engine works check it out here [Displaying data in Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data)

You can use [data_get()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-data-get) to get some data from variable which might not actually be there. For instance in your case you can do it like this

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Position: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="{{ data_get($enduser, 'eupos') }}" readonly="true">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read model binding documents your `users` function is belongsTo which means 1 so it's `user` and not users opposite of that `enduserticket` functio is hasMany so populate it to `endusertickets`

**PS**
And for show function you probably want to show `endtickets` of each user to themselves only and not everyone so i suggest you take care of that with providing validation (depend of your `usertickets` table if there is `user_id` column is the best if you validate authenticated user with that column this way each user only see their own tickets.